# Why can't I get e.RowIndex on row edit command of grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid in asp, with data keys say 'job_no' ,
I provided a onrowedit event and stored the event pararameter in 'e' as usual,like this

```
 protected void gvDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
```

but when I try to  access the relevant data key value of the row using row index like this,

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
```

,it gives me an error saying 'e' doesn't have a property called RowIndex.

Why is this happening ,is there any other way to get the data key value for the current row which is edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct one is as follows:

```
int id = Int32.Parse(gvDetails.DataKeys[Int32.Parse(e.NewEditIndex.ToString())].Values["job_no"].ToString());
```

Comment: [] is for array index. DataKeys is a collection `public virtual DataKeyArray DataKeys { get; }` So he is taking an index in that array.

Comment: I think i have use the right syntax,as I have used the same thing for another form,but that time for rowupdate event instead of rowedit event....anyway changing [] to() didn't help

Comment: You can try the second one..@Snedden27

Comment: I have only one data key i.e job number....besides the error specifically mention that e(i.e grid event) doesn't have a property called as rowIndex